# How to use CRLs in pyOpenSSL?

Tags: sockets, ssl, openssl, pyopenssl, python-cryptography

I looked extensively online if this question was answered elsewhere and it was not.

When trying to use CRLs in the python openssl library, we are getting "certificate unknown" errors. Specifically, when the crl has a revocation of a cert that is not used in the handshake of the ssl connection, there is still an error. If instead an empty CRL is used, there is no error and the devices are able to complete a socket.connect()

Simple client/server model to illustrate problem:

Server:

```
def createServerSideSocket(port, backlog=5):
    context = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile="cert.pem", keyfile="key.pem", password='tempPassword')
    context.verify_flags = ssl.VERIFY_CRL_CHECK_LEAF  #specifying flag to check crl
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile = "crl.pem") #loading crl
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.bind(('', port))
    sock.listen(backlog)    #listen on port 5000
    return sock, context

port = 5000
sock, context = createServerSideSocket(port)
newSocket, fromAddr = sock.accept()
connStream = context.wrap_socket(newSocket, server_side=True)
print(bytes.decode(connStream.recv(1024)))  #receive and print data
```

Client:

```
def createClientSideSocket(server_ip):
    context = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH, cafile="cacert.pem")  
    context.verify_flags = ssl.VERIFY_CRL_CHECK_LEAF #specifying flag to check crl
    context.load_verify_locations("crl.pem") #loading crl
    conn = context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(), server_hostname=server_ip)
    return conn

conn = createClientSideSocket("192.168.1.7") #our IP address of the server
conn.connect(("192.168.1.7", 5000))
conn.sendall(str.encode("test data"))
```

**When crl.pem has 0 revoked certs, connection works. When crl.pem has any revocation (even for revocations not used in the handshake) it fails with the following error:**

on client:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)
```

on server:

```
[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN] sslv3 alert certificate unknown (_ssl.c:777)
```

Comment: CRL objects are managed here/like that in PyopenSSL: https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#crl-objects. You are not expected to do `cafile = "crl.pem"` this is counter ways, a CA certificate is not a CRL. A CRL lists all certificates that became invalid and should **not** be used anymore.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek yeah, we use this library to create CRLs, but then to use them with ssl.py (the python ssl wrapper for python sockets) you need to point to the crl location according to https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_verify_locations

Comment: I stand corrected then indeed. But very poor API  I think to mix CA and CRLs. I have just checked the Python 3.7 source code for this function, and it is really not clear that it does anything with CRLs... :-( It basically calls SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations with what it loaded from filesystem and this doc page https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html does not speak at all about CRLs...

Comment: yeah it is really poorly documented :(

Comment: Based on the source code I have seen, I see no way that it can work (with CRLs), so it is either far more magical than I understand or just not really implemented and the documentation is wrong.

Comment: well that's not good! Do you know any other way to use crls with python ssl?

Comment: If you already have parts with PyOpenSSL I would stick to it, and not go back to ssl. But I have no full example to give on that. OR, as tedious as it may be, do the checks yourself, using the CRL file(s) and the certificate, find if the certificate is in the CRL file. There are probably a lot of edge cases so finding a library doing it for you is best, but if it does not exist...